# After copying live drupal site to wamp server, local site still acts like fresh install

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, backup, wamp

I recently set up WAMP server on my Windows 7 machine.  I copied the code from my live Drupal 7 site to my local folder, and imported my database.  However, when I try to access my local site, I get the Drupal install page.  I'm not sure how Drupal tells whether it's a fresh install or not, so I'm not sure how to debug this.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you go through install? It should let you go through to the end of install then tell you there's already an installed site and ask if you want to view it

Comment: did you point the database name to the one used in your settings.php in local?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's because the `settings.php` file inside `sites/default` does not exist in your local version (was not copied during the backup).

Make sure that your backup contains ALL the contents of the folder `sites/default`. There is a probability they are not copied due to Drupal's default permissions for `sites/default` folder.

If that's the case, next time when you do a backup, it would be better if you compress the whole drupal folder and download it as one file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It turns out the only problem was that the user in the settings.php file had host "localhost" while the user that had access to the table had host "%".  Changing this to "localhost" solved the problem :)